# Row counting with aggregate functions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with counting all rows. My query is:

```
SELECT info.pid, Name, Addr, Phone, GROUP_CONCAT(URL) as URL
FROM info, images WHERE info.pid = images.pid AND place='$kraj' GROUP BY info.pid
```

I cant use `mysql_num_rows` since `group_concat()` creates a row (null values) even though there are no results.

I tried putting `COUNT()` inside query:

```
...GROUP_CONCAT(URL) as URL, COUNT(info.pid) as num FROM info...
```

but it counts separate rows for every join.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just filter out the null values? :

```
SELECT info.pid, Name, Addr, Phone, GROUP_CONCAT(URL) as URL
  FROM info
  JOIN images
    ON info.pid = images.pid
 WHERE place = ...
   AND URL IS NOT NULL
 GROUP
    BY info.pid
;
```

Comment: Works great, how does that affect peformance? is it faster than count?

Comment: @JamaicaBob: That will depend on the details of your tables, indices, and data, and on what you're doing with them; but in general, I wouldn't expect this to have any performance impact.